# Como emular o branch reset de expressões regulares em Java

Tags: java, regex

Tenho esta regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:([aeiou]+)[0-9]+|([123]+)[a-z]+)\\W+");
```

Basicamente, ela tem as seguintes partes:

- uma ou mais vogais minúsculas (`[aeiou]+`), seguido de um ou mais números (`[0-9]+`), **ou**
- os dígitos 1, 2 ou 3 (`[123]+`), seguido de letras minúsculas (`[a-z]+`)
- tudo isso seguido por um ou mais caracteres que não sejam alfanuméricos (`\W+`)

Tenho também dois [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): um para as vogais e outro para os dígitos 1, 2 ou 3.
Como estou usando [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`), isso quer dizer que apenas um desses grupos será capturado. Ex:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("ae123.");
if (m.find()) {
    int n = m.groupCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.format("grupo %d: %s\n", i, m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, apenas o primeiro grupo é capturado, e a saída é:

> grupo 1: ae
> grupo 2: null

Mas se a `String` for `"111abc!!"`, o segundo grupo é capturado, e a saída é:

> grupo 1: null
> grupo 2: 111

Ou seja, para saber qual grupo foi capturado, eu tenho que percorrê-los até achar algum que não seja nulo.

---

Em algumas engines de regex é possível usar [*branch reset*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#branchreset), usando `(?|` no início, o que faz com que a numeração dos grupos seja "resetada" a cada vez que uma alternância (`|`) é encontrada ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/uaQYYi/1)). Então *bastaria* mudar a regex para:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?|([aeiou]+)[0-9]+|([123]+)[a-z]+)\\W+");
```

O *branch reset* (`(?|`) faz com que tanto `([aeiou]+)` quanto `([123]+)` sejam o grupo 1 (como há uma alternância - ou é um, ou o outro - isso garante que somente uma destas expressões seja capturada). Assim, eu não precisaria testar se os grupos são nulos, eu poderia pegar o grupo 1 diretamente (`m.group(1)` teria o valor que quero, sem precisar fazer o `for` em todos os grupos, testando se é nulo).

Porém o Java não suporta *branch reset*, e o código acima lança uma exceção:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 2
(?|([aeiou]+)[0-9]+|([123]+)[a-z]+)\W+
  ^
```

Estou usando Java 8, mas pelo que vi na [documentação do Java 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), esta funcionalidade ainda não é suportada pela API de regex (e no [preview do Java 15](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) também não há menção a este recurso).

Vi também [esta solução para .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378077), que consiste em usar [*named groups*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) e colocar o mesmo nome em todos os grupos, mas em Java também não funciona:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(?<grupo>[aeiou]+)[0-9]+|(?<grupo>[123]+)[a-z]+)\\W+");
```

Este código lança uma exceção, pois [no Java não são permitidos grupos com o mesmo nome](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html#duplicate):

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Named capturing group <grupo> is already defined near index 36
(?:(?<grupo>[aeiou]+)[0-9]+|(?<grupo>[123]+)[a-z]+)\W+
                                    ^
```

Existe alguma maneira de emular o *branch reset* em Java ou a única solução é fazer um *loop* nos grupos, testando se são nulos?

Answer (score 8):

Encontrei uma alternativa não muito "elegante" (e com limitações, explicadas mais abaixo), usando [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
String regex = "(?:([aeiou]+)[0-9]+|([123]+)[a-z]+)\\W+";
System.out.println("ae123.".replaceAll(regex, "$1$2"));
System.out.println("111abc!!".replaceAll(regex, "$1$2"));
```

Isto imprime:

> ae
> 111

O truque está no segundo parâmetro. `"$1$2"` significa que estou concatenando o grupo 1 (`$1`) com o grupo 2 (`$2`). Como existe uma alternância na regex (`|`), somente um dos grupos será capturado e o outro estará vazio, então ao concatená-los, o resultado sempre será o valor do grupo que foi capturado.

---

Mas como dito no início, esta abordagem tem algumas limitações. Supondo que a regex seja um pouco mais complicada, com vários grupos:

```
(1) | (2) (3) (4) | (5) (6) | (7) | (8)
```

Neste caso, eu posso ter somente o grupo 1 capturado, **ou** somente os grupos 2, 3 e 4, **ou** somente 5 e 6, **ou** somente 7, **ou** somente 8. Eu ainda poderia usar `replaceAll` com `"$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8"`, mas no caso de ter os grupos 2, 3 e 4, eles seriam concatenados e eu não teria como obter o valor de cada um separadamente. A menos que eu use algum separador, como `"$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8"` e depois faça um `split`, mas aí já começa a ficar "gambiarra" demais.

Com *branch reset*, a numeração dos grupos ficaria:

```
(?| (1) | (1) (2) (3) | (1) (2) | (1) | (1) )
```

E bastaria fazer um loop simples nos grupos (sempre começando com 1 e indo até `m.groupCount()`).

*Ou seja, continuo aguardando outras soluções*

Comment: Acredito que não dê para simular branch reset de uma maneira limpa no Java.

Comment: @VictorStafusa É, eu estava tentando alguns malabarismos com regex, e estou começando a achar que ou não é possível, ou até é, mas não vale a pena a complicação. Mas vamos esperar, vai que alguém surge com uma resposta :-)

Answer (score 2):

Até o momento a [versão atual do Java é a 16](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/16/), e ainda não temos disponível o *branch reset*. Sendo assim, uma outra alternativa - ainda longe do ideal - é usar [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([aeiou]+(?=\\d+\\W+)|[123]+(?=[a-z]+\\W+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ae123. 111abc!!");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

O código acima faz com que tanto o `ae` quanto o `111` estejam no grupo 1, simulando o comportamento do *branch reset* (assim, não preciso testar se o *match* está no grupo 1 ou 2).

Basicamente, eu uso uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o `|`, que significa "ou") com duas opções. A primeira procura pelas vogais, e com um *lookahead* que verifica se depois delas tem `\\d+\\W+` (dígitos e `\W+`). Mas como esta última parte está dentro do *lookahead* - ou seja, dentro de `(?= )` - isso não fará parte do *match*, já que os *lookarounds* são *zero-length assertions*: eles só verificam se algo existe (daí o *assertion*), mas seu conteúdo não é retornado no *match* (daí o "*zero length*").

A segunda opção procura pelos dígitos 1, 2 ou 3, e o que vem depois (as letras e o `\W+`) ficam em outro *lookahead*.

Tudo isso fica entre parênteses, formando um único grupo de captura. Assim, ou as vogais, ou os números 1, 2 ou 3 (mas não o que vem depois deles) estarão neste grupo. Por isso o `Matcher` só precisa verificar o grupo 1.

---

Isso pode resolver os casos mais simples, mas e se eu quisesse pegar dois grupos? Por exemplo, se os números que vem depois das vogais, e as letras depois do 1/2/3 também tivessem que ficar em um grupo (ou seja, no grupo 2). Com branch reset, bastaria fazer:

```
(?|([aeiou]+)([0-9]+)|([123]+)([a-z]+))\W+
```

Mas usando os *lookarounds*, eu teria que fazer uma solução similar, colocando outra alternância no grupo 2:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([aeiou]+(?=\\d+\\W+)|[123]+(?=[a-z]+\\W+))(\\d+|[a-z]+)(?=\\W+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ae123. 111abc!!");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "\t" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

No caso, o grupo 2 é um pouco mais simples, pois tem apenas os dígitos ou as letras. O problema é a redundância, pois tenho que repetir os dígitos e letras nos *lookaheads* do grupo 1, e novamente no grupo 2. Isso porque o *lookahead* só olha o que tem à frente, mas depois volta para onde estava (no caso, ele volta para o ponto imediatamente depois do grupo 1). Para que os caracteres no grupo 2 sejam consumidos e façam parte do *match*, é preciso colocá-los novamente na expressão.

Ou seja, se tivessem mais grupos, ficaria ainda mais redundante, com partes da expressão se repetindo várias vezes, a ponto de se tornar impraticável.
Sem contar que isso ainda não resolve muito bem os casos em que cada alternância pode ter uma quantidade diferente de grupos (a regex ficaria ainda mais complicada de entender e manter).

---

Ou seja, continua não existindo uma boa solução que atenda bem a todos os casos. Talvez o jeito seja fazer como sugere a pergunta: iterar pelos grupo, verificando se é `null`.